# Factorial Using FFT

Tags: c

I'm trying to implement a program in **C** that calculates the **factorial** of a very large n (up to a million), using **fft** and **binary splitting method**.

I've implemented a simple **library** to represent **arbitrary precision integer**.
To calculate the **fft** and **ifft**, i use **twofft.c** and **four1.c** routines from "**Numerical Recipes in C**"

Up to a certain n, all goes right, but when the numbers (floating arrays) are too big, the **ifft** (calculate with four1),after normalization and rounding, has values that are wrong.

**For example**, if i have two number with 2000 digits that ends with 40 zeros, and i have to multiply them each other (using fft), when i calculate the ifft, some ending zeros become "one".
this happens because when i rounded one of this "**zeros**", (0,50009 for examples), they became "**one**".
Now, i don't know if is my implementation wrong or if i have to rounding this numebrs in a different way.
I've tried to use both **binary split method** and **prime factorization**, but for **n >= 9000**, the result is **wrong**.

there is a way to resolve this? 
thanks for your attention and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Please format your question properly! And apart from that, `C` is not capable of handling such large numbers.

Comment: Please post a minimal code example that illustrates your issue.

Comment: @bash.d: OP did clearly state, that s/he implemented and uses an arbitrary precision integer library for the task at hand.

Comment: @datenwolf Sorry, wasn't able to read that through the horrible indentation

Comment: @bash.d: Apply yourself for one semester as a TA in a applied numerics class. That really trains your problem-description deciphering skills ;) – or to say it in other words: I had it much, much worse.

Comment: @datenwolf sounds funny, but I am happy I survided my 3 semesters of math. I hated numerics ;) But godd, there are people who are willing to go through this

Comment: To OP: I wonder why you do Fourier transform toward floating point. Your problem like yours should be tackled with a unnormalized integer Fourier transform, to eliminate floating point roundoff problems.

Comment: @datenwolf i use a floating point arrays, because the twofft routine need floating point arrays:

`void twofft(float data1[], float data2[], float fft1[], float fft2[],unsigned long n);`

Comment: To illustrate the issues I should post all the code of the program, because it must be execute.
I can post the result of 10.000! if you want, to see what is the issues.

Comment: Just to be clear: you are doing this for fun/to learn, right?  If not then it's senseless to implement your own bignum libraries and FFT.  Use GMP and have it over with.

Answer (score 1):

How do you represent arbitrary precision integers?

I mean what type are you actually using?

Can you please show us your code?

If you feel really lazy you can clone this project i've made few months ago:
https://github.com/nomadster/ESP

Edit:

By further reading your post i suppose by this statement

"this happens because when i rounded one of this "zeros", (0,50009 for examples), they became "one""

that you are still unaware of the fact that fft multiplication only works when the roundoff error is smaller than 0.5.
So it seems to me (if and only if i've correctly interpreted your cryptic message) that you are using a floating point type that doesn't have the required precision.

Answer (score 1):

For the record:

I also noticed wrong values returned by ifft from four1.c from numerical recipes. I only tested it with N=256 complex values as input, assembled in a way, that they should result in a real only time domain signal.

The resulting time domain vector has to be mirrored (end to start and vice versa ...) and shifted by one to correspond with the IFFTs of other implementations. (I tested numpy.fft.ifft, octave's ifft and a inverse discrete fourier transformation without any optimisation, simply based on the IDFT formula, which should be definitly correct).

There has to be a fundamental algorithm fault in the version provided by numerical recipies. In their books nothing related to this problem is described.